# SPContext of Application Page in Modal Dialog

Tags: spcontext

I'm trying to get a specific group out of the group collection of the current SPContext.
The current SPContext is hosted in a Application Page, which is displayed in a Modal Dialog.

The web instance is the right one but I'm missing some SPGroups in the SPGroupCollection.

Is there known an issue? In which way I can solve the problem?

Greetz, Hagen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your group has probably no specific permissions on the current SPWeb. Try the SPWeb.SiteGroups instead of SPWeb.Groups. You're gonna access all the site collection groups in that way. Take a look at that link : http://blog.tylerholmes.com/2007/09/spwebgroups-vs-spwebsitegroups.html